# C++ - share a library among dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, dynamic, static, modular

I developed a C++ modular program which loads its modules dynamically. Each module needs a specific static library and I linked this static library to each module. Is there any way to share this static library among all modules without linking it to them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Instead of static library, create dynamic library (`so` on *nix or `dll` on Windows) and link your modules against this dynamic lib.

Comment: if i link my modules against this dynamic lib, whether this lib load to memory one time or multiple times?

Comment: @peter It will be loaded into memory just one time.